# How to consume artifacts published by CI pipeline in CD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, cicd

I have CI and CD pipelines using Azure DevOps for a frontend angular project. Both are separate pipelines.

Here goes the YAML file for the CI pipeline which produces published artifact: output_final.zip. The below pipeline leverages Azure Pipelines for generating the published artifact.

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- integration

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- powershell: |
   $buildNumber="$(Build.BuildNumber)"
   echo $buildNumber  > src/version.txt
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files of UI'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'dist/source'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output'
    OverWrite: true
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output/'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output/output_final.zip'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output/output_final.zip'
    ArtifactName: drop
```

Now I have a separate CD pipeline which leverages self hosted private agent. In this CD pipeline, I want to consume artifacts published by the CI pipeline in the CD pipeline

Can anyone help me to know how to consume artifacts published by the CI pipeline and use it in the  CD pipeline with some sample YAML example.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the Publish Pipeline Artifact task to publish the CI artifact. Then, in your CD pipeline, use the Download Pipeline Artifact to consume it.
You can configure the download task to get the artifact from the current run or from a specific run. In your case, it sounds like you want a specific run since the CI pipeline is separate.

Here's an example of what the yaml tasks might look like:

```
#CI Task
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: '<Some Artifact Name>'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
    
#CD Task example
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: ''
    definition: ''
    specificBuildWithTriggering: true
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three options on how to approach this scenario:

**Option 1: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2**

By using DownloadPipelineArtifact and connect it to the latest Build of the CI Pipeline, as already mentioned by @Steve L., you should use ‘specific’ buildType and link it to the latest run of a CI Pipeline, and you can also filter on Branch and so on.
buildType : ‘Current’ in this case is useless. It refers to the same pipeline run, so if you wish to consume a CI published Artifact, and you have a sperate CD pipeline, you will not consume anything.
There is one small drawback of this scenario. You cannot easily Rollback. You have to specify the specific build manually, if you wish “kind off” rollback.

**Option 2: Use Build and Deploy Stages**

Build and Deploy doesn’t sound really like two Stages in the classical meaning, where we define Environments. But in a case you build one pipeline, you can create 2 Stages: Build and Deploy. In case of Build Stage you deploy your Artifact with Publish Pipeline Artifact and in Stage Deploy you can consume the artifact, in this case it’s buildType : ‘Current’, since you are refereeing to the current build run pipeline publish. So here you have a clear artifact version link between build and deploy. And, you can Rollback to this by going to the Build Summary, under Stages, you have the option “Rerun stage”. In case you Rerun for Deploy, you will consume the right Artifact of that point in time deployment (not the latest produced, as in option 1).
Example yaml code:

```
trigger:
- master

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    - job: Build_Job
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      
      #build steps

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/build' #your build path
          artifact: 'artifactdrop'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'

  - stage: Deploy_Prod
    dependsOn: Build
    jobs:
    - job: Deploy_Job
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest       
      steps:
        - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          displayName: 'DownloadPipelineArtifact'
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            artifactName: 'artifactdrop'
            targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/artifact'
        
        #publish steps
```

In the build Summary you can Rerun the stage with the published artifact:

[image]

**Option 3: Use Deployment Jobs in CD Pipeline**

In case you will use 2 separate YAML pipelines, you can also consume the CI Pipeline in a CD Pipeline with resources YAML syntax and deployment jobs. CD Pipeline with simple runOnce strategy:

```
pr: none
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: cd-pipeline-name
    source: ci-pipeline-name
    trigger: true

stages:
  - stage: Deploy_TEST
    jobs:
      
    - deployment: Test
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      environment: Test #optional, if you wish to deploy to Azure DevOps Environments, which offers a good deployment overview for YAML
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:        
            steps:

            #publish steps, that consume the artifact under: $(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/cd-pipeline-name/artifact-name/
```

Now in this case, the deploy part of the deployment job will download the consumed artifact automatically and put it under '$(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/cd-pipeline-name/artifact-name/'

For more information look into: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops